# Loop through one table's debit amount to find another tables matching credit amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of accounts receivable transactions where I need to allocate payments to invoices automatically. I am battling to come up with a SQL script that will match the debits in one column to the credits in another column. I was thinking of making two temp tables from the transactions table, one for debits and one for credits but I'm not sure how to loop through each row in the tables to find the matching debit-credit allocation and insert it into an allocations table

For example:

**Transactions**

| ID | AccountLink | Date | Reference | Descr | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | CUS001 | 2012/01/03 | INV001 | Invoice to Customer 1 | 3000.00 | 0 |
| 4 | CUS004 | 2012/01/04 | INV002 | Invoice to Customer 4 | 2500.00 | 0 |
| 5 | CUS001 | 2012/01/06 | PMT001 | Customer Payment | 0 | 3000.00 |

**Temp_Debits**

| ID | Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | INV001 | 3000.00 |

**Temp_Credits**

| ID | Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | PMT001 | 3000.00 |

**Allocations**

| From ID | To ID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 3000 |

**The transactions would be matched with a specific given account link, the inv-payment link have to be from that same account link and the matching transactions have to be within a 3 month period of each other

As stated by @Fabio, To link payments to invoices most of the systems using invoice reference where payee is required to provide same reference with the payment. Payment without reference always goes to manual matching. In this case any payment can match to any invoice as long as its in the same 3 month period.

Comment: The `JOIN` should do the work. What is the condition to match rows between tables?

Comment: What about if you have several $3000 transactions? Say A gave 3000 to B and C gave 3000 to D, would you be fine matching A/D and C/B?

Comment: Conceptionally: How do you want to match those 2 columns? What if there are multiple transactions with the same value?

Comment: *the transactions have to be from the same account link* - Please, update table structures to include all the columns you need

Comment: @astentx I've added the necessary columns and updated requirements. All transactions must be linked to a specific account (say I decide to do allocations for customer 1 and each invoice-payment transaction link must be within 3 months of each other) Its okay if there is two transactions of the same value

Comment: To link payments to invoices most of the systems using invoice reference where payee is required to provide same reference with the payment. Payment without reference always goes to manual matching

Comment: @LaraBaker If there will be the same transaction from the same account with the same amount, how do you want to distinguish them?

Comment: @astentx In this case any invoice with the same amount can be paid off from the receipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop. What you're saying is "find all records for the same account where the debit in one row matches the credit in the other row, within 3 months of eachother." You can do that via a [self join.](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-self-join/)

As @GordonLinoff says, if you have more than one row that matches the criteria, you'll get multiple results; without more ways to distinguish the results, you'll need a human to figure it out. You will also not pick up invoices that were paid in more than one payment.

```
select c.ID as from_id, 
d.ID as to_id, 
c.credit as amount
from transactions c
inner join transactions d
where c.credit = d.debit
and   c.credit > 0
and   c.id <> d.id
and   c.accountLink = d.accountLInk
and   datediff('mm', c.date, d.date) <= 3
```

Comment: @larabaker . . . This will not work when there are multiple rows with the same amounts.  If that is an issue, ask a *new* question.